# Grid of divs using Jquery not loading correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to test to see if I can make a grid made of divs, and when you move your mouse over the grid cells, the color changes, while also leaving a trail.  However when I try to put it in sublimetext, the grid loads up with the cells, but the mouseover function doesn't work.  I have my js files in a js folder, and my css file in a css folder so it's all nice and neat.  I've loaded the exact same code into Jsfiddle and it works just fine.  Any idea why this isn't working?  I'm still extremely new programming :/

http://jsfiddle.net/smugfox/7vx3W/3/

```
<head>
    <title>grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
```

```
</body>



$(document).ready(function () {
for (var i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
    $('<div />', {
        'class': 'cell',
            'id': 'div' + i
    }).appendTo('body');
}
});

$('.cell').mouseover(function () {
$(this).stop(true).fadeTo(200, Math.random());
}).mouseleave(function () {
$(this).fadeTo(200, Math.random());
});
```

Comment: Try get the version that the jsfiddle are using.

Comment: Just to make sure if you are loading correct `js` and `css` files : view source code in a browser > click on the `js` and `css` link. If it shows proper code then you are loading the files correctly and if not fix it and that may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, I've loaded the file into both chrome and firefox, and both load up the css, and js files.  I'm not really sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Try adding jquery part outside the `$(document).ready{}` inside it

Comment: Bingo!  That's exactly what was not working.  Thanks Zword! :)